# flexible divs position horizontally and vertically with no gaps

Tags: css, html, stack

I would like to dynamic position divs horizontally and vertically with the same widths and different heights depending on the width of theirs container.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Te7Z6/38/)

I would like to stack them like

> | 1 | 2 |
>
> | 3 | 4 |
>
> | 5 |

the problem is there is white gap between divs.
Even if I add clear 1st and 5th on the left

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Te7Z6/40/)

I still get gaps.

Is it possible to achieve that with css ?

```
EDIT:
```

Container width may change (i.e. if user drag its border). Then divs inside should align correctly to occupy whole space inside. Possible results below:

> | 1 |
>
> | 2 |
>
> | 3 |
>
> | 4 |
>
> | 5 |

or

> | 1 | 2 | 3 |
>
> | 4 | 5 |

or

> | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
>
> | 5 |

or

> | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use only CSS I think the best for you is to set two columns. In the first column you'll put 1, 3 and 5 and in the second column 2 and 4. That way won't be any white spaces.

**EDIT:**
If you want to stack those divs without white spaces and still have a flexible layout you can't do it just in CSS but you can try with  [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)  a jQuery plugin that is really easy to use.

Comment: the thing is that container's width can change and there might be 1-n columns

Comment: I think I don't fully understand. Can you provide any example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank You for the hint about Isotope

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I made a class column and have the columns with the content in them. May not be what you need, but it will work...

http://jsfiddle.net/Te7Z6/41/

Comment: it is the same as Lautaro advised but it is insuficient solution for me.

Comment: it's the obvious solution, but a very poor one..which will fail in many cases